# Accessing and updating array of embedded document dynamically with go

Tags: mongodb, go, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the following document model in mongo db

```golang
{
    "_id": "1",
    "name": "A",
    "address": "XYZ",
    "skills": [
        {
            "language": "JAVA",
            "experience": 5,
            "addons": {
                "tools": "Maven",
                "framework": "Spring"
            }
        },
        {
            "language": "PYTHON",
            "experience": 4,
            "addons": {
                "tools": "Pip",
                "framework": "Keras"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to replace the `addons` field based on the `language` criteria.
Consider I have two map as below. Both maps contains values in it

```
languageMap map[string]string; // stores language name as key and value
languageAddOnsMap map[string]AddOns; // stores language name as key and addons as a struct
```

Here is the Go BSON Aggregation Pipeline Query for the above replace

```
// Filter the document
filter := bson.D{{Key:"_id", Value:1}}

// Update the addons field
setFields := bson.D{{
            Key:"$set", Value:bson.D{{
            Key: "skills",
            Value: bson.D{
                {Key: "$map",
                    Value: bson.D{
                        {Key: "input", Value: "$skills"},
                        {Key: "as", Value: "skill"},
                        {Key: "in",
                            Value: bson.D{
                                {Key: "$switch",
                                    Value: bson.D{
                                        {Key: "branches",
                                            Value: bson.A{
                                                bson.D{
                                                    {Key: "case",
                                                        Value: bson.D{
                                                            {Key: "$eq",
                                                                Value: bson.A{
                                                                    "$$skill.language",
                                                                    languageMap["$$skill.language"] // doesn't work, when provided directly as string ("JAVA") it works 
                                                                },
                                                            },
                                                        },
                                                    },
                                                    {Key: "then",
                                                        Value: bson.D{
                                                            {Key: "$mergeObjects",
                                                                Value: bson.A{
                                                                    "$$skill",
                                                                    bson.D{
                                                                        {Key: "addons",
                                                                        Value: languageAddOnsMap["$$skill.language"], // doesn't work, when refered to some variable of addons it works
                                                                        },
                                                                    },
                                                                },
                                                            },
                                                        },
                                                    },
                                                },
                                            },
                                        },
                                        {Key: "default", Value: "$$skill"},
                                    },
                                },
                            },
                        },
                    },
                },
            },
          },
        },
    },
}
```

The above aggregation query in the `$mergeObjects` part doesn't update

```
{Key: "then",
    Value: bson.D{
        {Key: "$mergeObjects",
            Value: bson.A{
                "$$skill",
                bson.D{
                {Key: "addons",
                Value: languageAddOnsMap["$$skill.language"], // doesn't work, when refered to some variable of addons it works
                },
            },
        },
    },
}
```

the addons field when the Value is refered from the map `languageAddOnsMap["$$skill.language"]` (when $$skill.language) is used. But when value referred is a constant sting like `languageAddOnsMap["JAVA"]` the fields addons get updated in the document. So how could I refer that particular skill.language during the map operation?

Comment: I think for better readability and a chance to receive an answer, you should update the question to something more readable, all the query doesn't matter at all, try to minimize the example and be specific about the problem

Comment: Other than that, maybe you can run on the map, and do a different query for each value (with a filter that will only match documents which the skill value according to the map

Comment: @oren Updated. With the filter step I am able to fetch the document that needs to be updated. Now `skills` field of the document needs to be updated dynamically based on the language